# Position a HTML table element on top of img element

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to be able to place an html table on top of a image using css. I want to move my table up so that it looks like the picture below:

This is what I currently have it as:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is what my code looks like:

```html
<img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/sortByDivisionControl_BG2.png ")" width="570">
<table id="locations-table" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Locations
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>Anchorage, AK</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Spokane, WA</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Coburg, OR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>Kapolei, HI</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Toledo, WA</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Medford, OR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>Snohomish, WA</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Ridgefield, WA</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Redmond, OR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>Kent, WA</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Bend, OR</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a>Portland, OR</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What about using a background image?

Comment: Use pisition absolute  and top 0 for table

Answer (score 0):

This is what [background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) are for. I would do this instead:

```
<table id="locations-table" style="margin:0 auto; background-image: @Url.Content("~/images/sortByDivisionControl_BG2.png")">
```

Comment: I have tried this as well but I am getting a invalid value for the background image. The image has the correct path and everything but i think it has something to do with the size of the image. The image is 570 pixels x 61 pixels

Answer (score 0):

You can set z-index also using css.
For information :
[Check This](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)